# Submit form with ajax in spring 2 with simpleformcotroller

Tags: ajax, spring

I want send a form with ajax and i use a simple form controller in spring 2. Can i help me??
I have this view:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                   
    dataType: 'json',                    
    url: url,
    data: datos,
    beforeSend: mostrarLoader //funciones que definimos más abajo
    success: mostrarRespuesta  //funciones que definimos más abajo
});
```

and this method in controller:

```java
protected ModelAndView onSubmit
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your SimpleFormController is accessible (or mapped) at http://:app/create, then the AJAX code would be:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:8080/app/create', // Do not hardcode the url. This is just illustration
type: 'post',
data: $("form").serialize(), //Form URL encoded.
success: function (data) {
// Handle Success Here
},
error: function (xhr) {
//Handle Error Here
}
});
```

In your SimpleFormController onSubmit method, Form Parameters are bound to your command object or use HttpServletRequest's getParameter("") to get your Form data.

> protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) {
>
> MyObject obj=  (MyObject) command; //or request.getParameter("");
>        }